# asp.net how do you check the status code in the browser?

Tags: redirect

Say I have a web page which does a permanent redirect to another page. The status code sent should be 301. I would like to test this (ie to check that the status code is indeed 301) but the browser redirects automatically to the new page and I don't have the time to check the status code returned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddler is your friend here, it can monitor all web traffic and you will be able to see the 301 being sent back.

You can download it from http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

You can check your logs in IIS, it keeps track of requests and the response code it sent back.

You can also use a tool like Fiddler which works with IE and it will show you the request/response data.

Other browsers likely have their own tools that will show you this information also.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use a web debugging tool that will allow you to look at what requests and responses have been received by the browser.  [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a free, useful tool in seeing these items.